# Primefaces Autocomplete in Firefox not closing on Selection

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I'm Using Primefaces 5.0.9 with Wildlfy 8.1 and JSF 2.1.2

I have an autocomplete defined as follows:

```
<p:autoComplete label="CAT" id="CATEGORY" dropdown="true" value="#{UserDownloadFileBean.editUserFileCategory}" 
        completeMethod="#{UserDownloadFileBean.categoryAutoComplete}" converter="#{UserDownloadFileCategoryConverter}" forceSelection="true"
        var="item" itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please choose a category!" >
    <f:ajax event="itemSelect" update=":UploadFileCategoryDialogForm" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

This works perfectly fine with all browsers EXCEPT Firefox (tested with v32 and v34).
When I select an entry in the suggestions the panel doesn't hide. The only way to close it is to click outside. The firebug Console delivers this error:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined

Examining the generated javaScript Code the Problem is obvious:

```
function(){PrimeFaces.cw("AutoComplete","CATEGORY",{id:"createUserDownloadFileForm:CATEGORY",widgetVar:"CATEGORY",delay:300,deletionDelay:600,forceSelection:true,behaviors:{
            itemSelect:function(ext) {mojarra.ab('createUserDownloadFileForm:CATEGORY',event,'itemSelect',0,0,{'CLIENT_BEHAVIOR_RENDERING_MODE':'UNOBSTRUSIVE'})}}});});
```

The variable event is not existing (i guess other browsers provide it anyways?).
In the Showcase (Pf v5.1.7) the code uses Primefaces.ab and ext instead:

```
$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("AutoComplete","widget_j_idt88_event",{id:"j_idt88:event",widgetVar:"widget_j_idt88_event",delay:300,behaviors:{
            itemSelect:function(ext) {PrimeFaces.ab({s:'j_idt88:event',e:'itemSelect',p:'j_idt88:event',u:'j_idt88:msgs'},ext);}}});});
```

Was this fixed some time after 5.0.9 and if so is there a way to gain a working version in 5.0.9?
Otherwise what could i have done wrong that it does not use the same function?

Comment: The listener in the ajax should be in #{} (EL)... `#{UserDownloadFileBean.editUserFileCategoryChangeListener}`..

Comment: I removed the unused Listener and its wrong call. (Doesn't affect the problem)

Comment: Have you checked your console for any JS errors ?

Comment: 'ReferenceError: event is not defined' is all i get (occuring in the js code i posted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported as a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7669) to primefaces, and I posted a patch to their code to fix it.  In my case, I had to build a new jar in order to get this to work without converting the hundreds of f:ajax elements everything over to p:ajax.